# "Inheriting" annotations from one provider to another in Guice

Tags: java, guice

Say I have 2 classes.

```
class A { ... }
class B {
 public B(A a) {...}
}
```

I want to create a module which gets a name and needs to create a binding for annotated B:

```
class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  String name;
  public MyModule(String name) { this.name = name; }

  public void configure() {
    // CREATE BINDING for @Named(name)B which depends on @Named(name)A
  }
}
```

What would be the best way to create the binding for B (or a provider for it) which depends on the correct A?

Thanks
Yaron

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
bind(B.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("name")).toProvider( new Provider<B>() {

    private A namedA;

    @Inject
    public void setNamedA(@Named("name") A namedA ) {
        this.namedA = namedA;
    }      

    @Override
    public B get() {
        return new B( namedA );
    }

} );
```

It should work according to documentation though I haven't tested it.

Comment: It's a nice approach but I don't think it can work. Problem is that the 'name' is a parameter to the module so it can't be used as an annotation for the parameter of setNamedA.

Comment: Ops, I didn't have that into account. In that case, you could retrieve the named A using the Injector, using method getInstance(Key<T>key). That way you get the instance after the modules are already installed in Guice. Here's the javadoc for that method: http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#getInstance(com.google.inject.Key<T>)

Comment: I don't think you can do the binding by pure programatic declaration, as the strategy you want to use seems too complex for it to be abstracted by Guice fluent interface. That's why I think you must resort to some kind of Guice internal methods (like using Providers, or calling the Injector directly)

Comment: Using providers is becoming a problem when binding for @Names(name) A is optional. In this case I can't use getProvider() since if it's not bound Guice will kill the process. 
The only solution I found so far is injecting the injector into the providers. But I really think it's ugly.

Comment: I also think it's ugly, but I'm afraid it's your only option. Guice binding interface doesn't seem to be powerful enough to define what you are trying to do. You are trying to make two bindings depend on each other, and I think that is not supported. The bindings in Guice seem to be independent between them (at least looking at the API). Maybe looking at its source code you can find some workaround, but I doubt it is worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a very similar question this week in a [different SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14008377/1426891).

If you know which annotations you want to support, you'll be able to create a `PrivateModule` for each annotation so you can expose a `@Named("c1") B` to use only a `@Named("c1") A` wherever A needs to be bound.

```
install(new PrivateModule() {
  @Override void configure() {
    // These are only bound within this module, and are not visible outside.
    bind(A.class).to(A1.class);
    // Though you can bind to other bindings which come from outside!
    bind(B.class).to(Key.get(B.class, Names.named("c1")));
    // Now expose the annotated bindings you'd like to expose.
    bind(C.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("c1")).to(C.class);
    expose(C.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("c1"));
  }
});
```

I don't think there's a way to say "For all annotations N, make available `@N B` to use `@N A`, because Guice is built to be a fancy map from (Annotation, TypeLiteral) tuples to Providers, and you're asking to infer tuples that may or may not exist all the way down the dependency graph.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know all annotations beforehand.
But I do think it's something that can be added. Something in the form of "inherit annotation from another binding" somehow.